# graphviz : Why Does't it run _python

Tags: python, graphviz

```
import graphviz
with open('tree.dot') as f:
    dot_graph = f.read()
graphviz.Source(dot_graph)
```

I am trying to visualize DecisionTree by iris_data
but Graphviz is not running with the message below.

> CalledProcessError: Command '['dot', '-Kdot', '-Tsvg']' returned
> non-zero exit status 1. [stderr: b'There is no layout engine support
> for "dot"\r\nPerhaps "dot -c" needs to be run (with installer's
> privileges) to register the plugins?\r\n']

Worked to solve

1. again_ pip install graphviz
2. set os path : graphviz    * ~\bin , \bin\dot.exe
3. set os path : library    *\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\graphviz
4. uninstall graphviz and do again

I exactly install and set path and it seems to go well when it comes to graphviz_path. But, the error is still there. How can I handle it?

Comment: There is a suggestion in the error message itself, did you try that?

Comment: try but  I don't know what to do, what is mean "There is no layout engine support for "dot"    that error message pop out by cmd : dot -v

Comment: Oh. I got it, Thanks,  python graphviz lib version is 2.38!!  but installed(graphviz.gitlab.io) graphviz.exe version is 2.44.1. So I downloaded graphviz again in github_ver_2.38 and solved it